# I am having a do while loop issue. Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop

The code below is supposed to ask the user to enter start into the console and then if the user hits start "Let's begin" if not, "Wrong word entered" is printed and the method loops itself.

```
do { 
    System.out.println("Type start to play");
    String word = lineReader.nextLine();
    String word2 = ("start");
    boolean valid;

    valid =(word.equals (word2)); 

    if (valid){
        System.out.println("Let's begin");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong Word Entered");
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Comment: Indent your code!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your code when you post it - it makes it *much* easier for everyone to read it and then help you.

Comment: The problem is that you declare `valid` inside the loop, so you can't use it in the `while (!valid)` condition. Move `boolean valid` before the `do`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you declare `valid` inside the loop, so you can't use it in the `while (!valid)` condition.

The variable is only visible to inside the `do/while` loop if you declare it there (this is called the variable's "scope").

Move `boolean valid` before the `do`:

```
boolean valid;
do {
  // Code which assigns true or false to valid.
} while (!valid);
```